# Didn't get used to vs hadn't got used to

Tags: grammar

Are both options correct or just one of them?

They didn't get used to / hadn't got used to working hard, so they were sacked.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context.

[During the time that they worked there], they did not get used to working hard. (Talks about a period of time.) OR

[By the time they had worked there for six months], they had not got used to working hard. (Talks about the point in time when it was decided to sack them.)

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. You could also say They hadn't *gotten* used to working hard.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Is there any difference in meaning?

Comment: @SimoIta In US English we would say "hadn't *gotten* used to"; the *got used* version sounds incorrect.  I believe the *got* version is the common one in British English, though.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies.

Comment: @Kate now the difference is clear, thanks!

Comment: @stangdon I was aware of the difference between got (BE) and gotten (AE). However, thanks for writing it.